# saving time when user finishes quiz

Tags: php, jquery

Im creating a quiz for a client and I need a push in the right direction.

When the user starts the quiz a timer(count up) stars counting in milliseconds, seconds, minutes.
When all questions are correct the result is stored in a table with the number of attempts and time.

How can I ensure that the user does not just go into the DOM tree and edit time manually? Or just do a simple

```
$('#foo').disabled = false; 
$('#foo').val('0.0.1');
```

An idea that crossed my mined was to compare two different timestamps using php. 
One when the quiz starts and when a user submits the results, is this a bad practice? Or is it another way around?

Comment: I think doing the computation server side (php) would be your best bet.

Comment: there's nothing you can do to secure the time on the client. you have to store the start/end times on the server. e.g. they hit the start button, which causes an ajax request which sends over the quiz text and marks the test as started on the server.

Comment: do not rely on client side timers when you need to track time.  save a server side time-stamp when the quiz starts and again when they finish and just calculate the difference between the two times.

Comment: thanks @DerekS,  I'll go for server-side then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the user from manipulating the result you'll want to do the calculation on the server side, in PHP.

For example store the start time in a session variable `$_SESSION['quizStart'] = time()` (so it can be accessed on different pages) and when the form is completed PHP can save the end time: `$_SESSION['quizEnd'] = time()`.

The difference between these two variables is your duration: `$quizDuration = $_SESSION['quizStart'] - $_SESSION['quizEnd']`

Comment: thanks @Andrew I'll use server side to calc time then